# Error con el botón de envío de formulario

Tags: html, jquery

Tengo el siguente código, para el login de un sitio, pero el btn_enviar no hace nada y la consola no me muestra ningun error.  Al principio puse un alerta con "ok" o "mal" en el botón a ver si hacía algo, pero solo m mostraba "ok" aunque no estuviera la clase is-valid. ¿que pudiera ser? Gracias de antemano.

Si sabes cómo puedo agregar más código sin que me limiten, se los agradecería mucho.

```
<script>
    $("#text_correo").keyup(function(){
        if (!validarCorreo($(this))) {
           $(this).addClass("is-invalid");
        } else {
            $(this).removeClass("is-invalid");
            $(this).addClass("is-valid");
        }
    })

    $("#text_password").keyup(function(){
        if (!validarPass($(this))) {
            $(this).addClass("is-invalid");
        } else {
            $(this).removeClass("is-invalid");
            $(this).addClass("is-valid");
        }
    })

    $("#text_confirnar").keyup(function(){
        if (!confirmar($("#text_password"), $(this))) {
            $(this).addClass("is-invalid");
        } else {
            $(this).removeClass("is-invalid");
            $(this).addClass("is-valid");
        }
    })

    $("#btn_enviar").click(function(){
        if ($("#text_correo").hasClass("is-valid") && 
            $("#text_password").hasClass("is-valid") && 
            $("#text_confirnar").hasClass("is-valid")) {
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    })
</script>
```

Código HTML:

```html
    ...  
    <main role="main">
        <div class="cabecera">
            <div class="container fondo_cabecera">
                <div class="text_cabecera">
                    <h1 class="display-4" >Sistema de Control de Estudiantes</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="container">
            <div class="cuerpo">
                <label for="text_correo">Correo</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="text_correo"><br>
                <label for="text_password">Contraseña</label>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="text_password"><br>
                <label for="text_confirnar">Confirmar contraseña</label>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="text_confirnar"><br>
                <button type="submit" id="btn_enviar" class="btn btn-success align-bottom" >Entrar</button>
                <hr>  
                <h6 class="text-muted">© Howard | 2020</h6>
            </div>
        </div> 
    </main>
    ...
```

Comment: bueno tal como indicas en tu pregunta el botón se llama `btn_enviar` pues tienes una typo has puesto `btn_eviar` te falta la **n**

Comment: Es verdad. Lo hice, le puse la n y aún así no hace nada

Comment: puedes añadir el `html`?

Comment: Actualice la pregunta. Puse el código HTML

Comment: si tu código está en fichero `jQuery_Validation.js` añade ese script antes de cerrar el tag `body`. Y otra cosa, estas cargando 2 veces la libreria jquery en el head y luego en el body.

Comment: Actualice de nuevo. Tengo problemas a la hora de agregar más código. Cómo puedo hacer para evitar eso??

Comment: el script debe ir luego del html así encuentra los elementos

Comment: Quite el HTML y el body para poder publicar lo k necesitaba. Si envío el código completo, no m dejará publicar. M pone k hay mucho código y poco comentarios, o algo así.

Comment: Cómo lo hiciste???

Comment: Te recarga la página al dar click en el boton?

Comment: Ya lo solucione. El problema estaba en k no tenía Tag form o eso creo, pq ya todo trabaja como debe ser. Entonces pienso k la etiqueta form es fundamental a la hora de hacer comas como estás. Gracias x sugerirme ideas para arreglar mi código.